# Efficiently Setting up Sparse Matrices in MATLAB for Matrix Inversion

Tags: performance, matlab, math, matrix, matrix-inverse

Consider the following weighted solution to the normal equation for a least squares inverse problem:

```
m = inv(G'*W'*W*G)*G'*W'*W*d
```

I would like to set up the weighting matrix `W`, which is a square diagonal matrix with weights on the diagonal.

As I have a large number of data points in d (10⁷), my system matrix `G` is also large, but only in one dimension (as I have far more data points than model parameters). In the case of 6 model parameters, `G` is of size (10⁷ × 6). Hence, `W` has to be of size (10⁷ × 10⁷). However, it is sparse, with only 10⁷ non-zero entries (the weights).

To reduce memory, I use sparse on `W`.

To assign weights, I do the following

```
d = [d1;d2];   
W = sparse(length(d),length(d)) 
w1 = length(d2)/length(d);
w2 = length(d1)/length(d);
W(1:length(d)+1:length(d)*length(d1)) = w1;
W(length(d)*length(d1)+1:length(d)+1:end) = w2;
```

`d1` and `d2` are column vectors with observations.

This will assign weights to the diagonal, but it is awfully slow.

My question:

Can I either

- Somehow speed up the assignments of weights to the diagonal, or
- Re-write `m = inv(G'*W'*W*G)*G'*W'*W*d` so that I do not have to set-up `W` at all?

Note 1: In the shown weights are two different constants, but in practice they will vary allowing the diagonal!

Note 2: The bottle neck of the code is indeed setting up `W`, not the inversion itself, as the inverted matrix is only of size (6 × 6).

Comment: What are `d1` and `d2`? Please post runnable code. Also, `d = [d1;d2]` implies `w1` and `w2` are just ones and `W` is `eye`? Why _two_ diagonal assignments (last two lines)?

Comment: @LuisMendo I edited the code. However, I don't see why W should be eye. w1 and w2 are weightes, in this case depending on the length of the respective observation vector. But they could be any float.

Comment: `d = [d1;d2]` implies `length(d1)==length(d2)`. So `w1` and `w2` are `1`

Comment: d = [d1;d2] is a vertical concatenation of n x 1 and m x 1 vectors and as such does not imply anything on the length of d1 and d2 except length(d1)+length(d2) = length(d)

Comment: Ah, ok. I thought they were row vectors. You should indicate that in the question

Comment: Have you tried using `W = sparse([1:numel(d1) 1:numel(d2)], 1:numel(d), [w1; w2], numel(d), numel(d));`, where `w1` and `w2` are column vectors? This replaces the intiallization `W = sparse(length(d),length(d));` and the two assignment lines

Comment: @LuisMendo: Great, I did not realize such initialization of sparse matrices was possible. It's actually even given in the documentary. It is faster by several orders of magnitude. Thanks a lot!

Comment: If the weights matrix is diagonal, then W' = W and W'W is also a diagonal matrix with squared weights on the diagonal.  I think this could be represented as a vector and handled specially on the multiplication.

Comment: With the code you provided, your matrix `W` is not diagonal, but rather, a horizontal concatenation of two diagnoal matrices. This will fail the matrix inversion, because this makes `G.'·W.'·WG` singular. Can you check if the code is correct by looking at `full(W)` for a small toy problem?

Comment: If `W` is truly diagonal, then you can better do `bsxfun(@times, G, [length(d2) length(d1)]/length(d))` to compute `G.' · W.'`. What are `WG` and `Wd`?

Comment: @RodyOldenhuis: I edited the post. It was not very readable. Now the multiplication signs should make it clearer. W is and was truly diagonal, also with my first approach. I checked it with full on a subset.

Comment: But if I do `d1 = rand(3,1); d2 = rand(5,1);` and then execute the code above for constructing `W`, I do not get a diagonal matrix...

Answer (score 0):

By the structure of `W` I'd say it is more efficient to split `G` into two halves and calculate the products with `W` as scalar products:

```
G1 = G(1:length(d1),:);
G2 = G(length(d1)+1:end,:);

m = (w1^2*G1'*G1 + w2^2*G2'*G2) \ (w1^2*G1'*d1 + w2^2*G2'*d2);
```

Also, generally use `A \ b` instead of `inv(A)*b` (even if `A` is small).